# Dropdownlist bind recent twelve Month-Year format in C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind the values to the dropdown.
I need to bind previous 12 month-year format as below

This is how i want to bind the data.

Binding Text:
March 2015
February 2015
January 2015
December 2014
November 2014
October 2014
September 2014
August 2014
July 2014
June 2014
May 2014
April 2014

Binding Value:
3 2015
2 2015
1 2015
12 2014
11 2014
10 2014
9 2014
8 2014
7 2014
6 2014
5 2014
4 2014

Appreciate your time.
Thanks

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you will get a much better response from this site if you have tried something first and ask why it is not working. Try googling for some examples of databinding in asp.net, follow those examples.

Comment: ok good luck with your requirements/homework ! If you want an answer you should show some effort first !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
for (int i = -11; i <= 0; i++)
   {
      var d = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i);
      var dStartingFromDayOne = new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, 1);
      var ds = dStartingFromDayOne.ToString("MMMM yyyy");
      Console.WriteLine(ds);
   }
```

Using linq

```
var last12Months = Enumerable.Range(-11, 12).Select(i => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i)).Select(d => new DateTime(d.Year,d.Month,1).ToString("MMMM yyyy"));
```